# Resolver o problema dos acentos no nome das colunas

Tags: php

Boa noite,

Preciso de ajuda a resolver os problemas dos acentos, tanto no título da página como nos nomes que eu atribuí às colunas, mostro exemplo na imagem em anexo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: tenta

'ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = Latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci';

Comment: Tenho isso <meta charset="utf-8"> no inicio da página. Mas o que me retorna da base de dados não tenho problemas com acentos, só tenho com os nomes que eu atribuí e que ão retornam da base de dados

Comment: Se eu utilizar este código:

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);

mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysqli_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysqli_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

o que retorna da base de dados retorna bem, mas o que eu escrevo fica com erros, se retirar esse código o que eu escrevo fica sem erros e o que retorna da base de dados fica com erros, alguém consegue uma solução?

Comment: O erro esta no tipo de documento a decodificação no netbeans, você pode definir como quer trabalhar o charset, o recomendado é fazer tudo em UTF8

Comment: qual é o editor que você esta utilizando?

Comment: Notepad++, já converti para UTF8 e continua a dar o mesmo problema